# Can't generate signed APK in Android Studio, 'java.io.IOException'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a problem with generating signed APK in Android Studio. It was working fine few days ago, I dont know what went wrong. I'm getting this error for any project I try to fgenerate signed APK of:

> Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/bhaveshmisri/Downloads/littleone-dagger-mvp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/release/jars/3/1f/main.jar] (Can't read [/Users/bhaveshmisri/Downloads/littleone-dagger-mvp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/RealmTransformer/release/folders/1/1/realm(;;;;;;**.class)] (Can't read [com] (Can't read [crashlytics] (Can't read [android] (Can't read [answers] (Can't read [shim] (Can't read [R.class] (Duplicate zip entry [com/crashlytics/android/answers/shim/R.class]))))))))

Here is my buildTypes Task:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        shrinkResources false // This must be first
        minifyEnabled false   // This must be after shrinkResources
        multiDexEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules-debug.pro"
    }
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        multiDexEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
```

Here is the code I've written in proguard file:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dump class_files.txt
-printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-repackageclasses ''

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class * extends android.app.
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keep class com.google.common.collect.MapMakerInternalMap$ReferenceEntry
-keep class com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$ReferenceEntry

-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService


-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}


-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.* { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation,Signature
-dontwarn in.mylo.pregnancy.baby.app.**
-keep class in.mylo.pregnancy.baby.app.shapeimageview.**{ *; }

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }

-keep class butterknife.*
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
 @butterknife.* <methods>; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
 @butterknife.* <fields>; }


-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn javax.inject.**
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe

-dontwarn java.lang.ClassValue
-dontwarn com.google.j2objc.annotations.Weak
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement


-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}

-dontwarn com.firebase.**
-dontnote com.firebase.client.core.GaePlatform

-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }

-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.clevertap.android.sdk.**


-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontnote okhttp3.**

-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-dontwarn android.support.**

-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-dontwarn com.fasterxml.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn com.caverock.**
-dontwarn com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.**


-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn com.octo.android.robospice.retrofit.RetrofitJackson**
-dontwarn retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.inject.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.** { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**

-dontwarn sun.misc.**

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
   long producerIndex;
   long consumerIndex;
}

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
   long producerNode;
   long consumerNode;
}

-keep class in.mylo.pregnancy.baby.app.retrofit.** { *; }

-keep interface org.parceler.Parcel
-keep @org.parceler.Parcel class * { *; }
-keep class **$$Parcelable { *; }

-keepnames public class * extends io.realm.RealmObject
-keep @io.realm.annotations.RealmModule class *
-keep class io.realm.** { *; }
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn io.realm.**

-keepnames public class * extends io.realm.RealmObject


-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.location.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.gcm.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.iid.**

-keep class com.google.android.gms.gcm.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.iid.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.location.** { *; }

-keep class com.moe.pushlibrary.activities.** { *; }
-keep class com.moengage.locationlibrary.GeofenceIntentService
-keep class com.moe.pushlibrary.InstallReceiver
-keep class com.moengage.push.MoEPushWorker
-keep class com.moe.pushlibrary.providers.MoEProvider
-keep class com.moengage.receiver.MoEInstanceIDListener
-keep class com.moengage.worker.MoEGCMListenerService
-keep class com.moe.pushlibrary.models.** { *;}
-keep class com.moengage.core.GeoTask
-keep class com.moengage.location.GeoManager
-keep class com.moengage.inapp.InAppManager
-keep class com.moengage.push.PushManager
-keep class com.moengage.inapp.InAppController


-dontwarn com.moengage.location.GeoManager
-dontwarn com.moengage.core.GeoTask
-dontwarn com.moengage.receiver.*
-dontwarn com.moengage.worker.*
-dontwarn com.moengage.inapp.ViewEngine

-keep class com.delight.**  { *; }

-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.location.**
-keep class com.moe.** { *; }
-keep class com.moengage.** { *; }
-keep class com.delight.** { *; }

-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.** { *; }



-keep class com.facebook.** {
   *;
}



-dontwarn android.databinding.**
-keep class android.databinding.** { *; }
```

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Since those warnings. You can add the below line in your proguard to ignore the warnings.
`-dontwarn com.crashlytics.android.answers.shim.**`

Comment: Can you please post your proguard file?

Comment: @Geek done, added the proguard file as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in answers library. There seems to be a problem in the latest version. When i downgrade the library to

`compile('io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.5.9') {
        exclude module: 'answers-shim'
    }`

it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to disbale proguard for release build?

```
release {
    shrinkResources false
    minifyEnabled false
    useProguard false
    multiDexEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), "proguard-rules.pro"
}
```

if this works, you should fix our proguard config

Comment: Tried, but still didnt work. It's not even syncing project if i disable proguard.

Answer (score 0):

Try excluding answers-shim:

```
compile ('io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+') {
    exclude module: 'answers-shim' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below line in your proguard file to ignore warning that you are getting as above.

```
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.android.answers.shim.**
```

Comment: Try to import  any class from shim package and see what are the suggestion available to import, From that, you can find out what are the libraries have the same class names which are contradicting while you are building.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

The same problem occurred to me after I :

- Upgraded to Android Studio 3, then
- in my dependency library, changed inline classes to lambdas and method references.

I thought I could freely utilize lambdas and method references as stated in Android Studio 3 release notes, I may have forgot or missed it.

### Solution:

Anyway, I'm not 100% sure, but I think we still can't use lambdas and/or method references in project libraries, because as soon as I reverted all lambdas and method references in my library, I successfully re-generated my APK.